# Login check in jhipster

Tags: java, jhipster

This might be a very naive question but for some reason it is bugging me as I have to implement a part related to it in my application. Don't ask me why.

**Step 1:**
I installed the jhipster application and ran it on my local machine. This created all schemas and databases by itself.

**Step 2:**
I login using admin.

Question
Where in the code is the check about username and password mentioned? Which means when does it hit the database and gets the password for a particular username, decrypt it and compares it with what is being submitted from the form

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you did not give details about authentication type, I can only give you a hint: look for the implementation of UserDetailsService interface and learn more about Spring Security.Nothing really specific to JHipster here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what security model you used while creating the project.

If authentication type

**1: Session**

Step 1: Open the class **SecurityConfiguration.java**

Step 2: In the configure method you will find something like this.

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

Check this class

**UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class**

You will find all your answers

**2: Oauth**

Step 1: Open the file **OAuth2ServerConfiguration.java**

Step 2: In the configure method you will find something like this.

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint)
    .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
    .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

Check this class

**UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class**

So the same class handles authentication, encoder is automatically called, as it is set in the configuration.

I hope that helps. I would encourage you to be more specific with your question.

PS: Jhipster Version : 4.3.0